# What is the eligibility criteria for giving FATWA?

Tags: fiqh, fatwa

I want to know who is eligible to give fatwa in all the schools of thoughts/fiqhs.

as far as i know in SHIA's only marja's can give fatwa.

what is the criteria in all other sects.

Comment: i am still waiting for answers

Comment: the first part of the wiki answers your question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatwa

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the detailed teachings of the Qur'an, Prophet S.A.W's Sunnah and Hadith. It is recommended that a scholar come forth with a fatwa as people not qualified in terms of authentic knowledge may only create more and more problems.

In the regard for being authentically knowledgeable, a Mufti or Alim is a preferred person to get a fatwa from. But it is advisable that a fatwa should come from a group of scholars instead of one. One person can be at fault or could make a mistake, but there is less likelihood of a complete group of scholars from making that mistake.

Answer (score -3):

## Sunni

We only take Fatawa from Big Scholars like

> ## Ibn Baz
>
> ## Uthaymeen
>
> ## Albani
>
> ## May Allah have mercy on them

Other Scholars should acknowledge a scholar that he is a Big Scholar
How they will do it? By knowing his level of knowledge in Qur'an, Hadith and Fiqh.

Check this site: https://islamqa.info/en